# Simple recursion counter

Tags: java, recursion, count

I have a simple recursive java file. The code is the following

```
public class Rekursion_SA_UE {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    count(1, 10);
}

public static int count(int zahl, int max)
{
    if(zahl>max) return zahl;
    else{
        System.out.println(zahl);
        count(zahl+1, max);
        return zahl;
    }
}
```

The output is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.
If I switch two lines it counts from 10 downwards. It looks like

```
 public class Rekursion_SA_UE {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    count(1, 10);
}

public static int count(int zahl, int max)
{
    if(zahl>max) return zahl;
    else{
        count(zahl+1, max);//switched
        System.out.println(zahl);//switched
        return zahl;
    }
}
```

The output here is 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1.
Why is that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add what you want to achieve and describe what your code should do, rather than just pasting it.

Comment: I fail to see why this question has been downvoted so much. The question is clear, the code is given, and if you don't already understand recursion, it's a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of when you call `count` vs. when you output the number.

In your first version, you output `zahl` **before** you recurse into `count`, and so you see the numbers in order. Something like this (I'll stop at 4, rather than 10):

```
count(1, 4)
    output 1
    count(2, 4)
        output 2
        count(3, 4)
            output 3
                count(4, 4)
                output 4
                    count(5, 4)
                    return
                return
            return
        return
    return
```

In your second version, you recurse *before* you output `zahl`, and so you go all the way into your recursion (ten levels), and then when it starts to unwind, you start outputting the numbers, deepest (10) first. Something like (again I'll just use 4, not 10):

```
count(1, 4)
    count(2, 4)
        count(3, 4)
            count(4, 4)
                count(5, 4)
                    return
                output 4
                return
            output 3
            return
        output 2
        return
    output 1
    return
```

To understand behavior like this, use a debugger and single-step through the code. There's no need, in 2013, to guess at what code is doing. You can *watch* it run and see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Thanky you very much, that explained it.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how recursion works. It's like a tree. Your first snippet is like:

```
call(1)
    print(1)
    call(2)
        print(2)
        call(3)
            //etc.
```

Your second snippet is like:

```
 call(1)
     call(2)
         call(3)
             //etc.
         print(3)
     print(2)
 print(1)
```